# AWK: script to add column values based on 2nd column "name total"

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file in below pattern

```
LLCMO   101986
ONE 102419
PAZ 10478
ONE 107788
ONE 108377
NXT 11
PORTA   111170
PORTA   112005
PORTA   114075
LLCMO   114198
PORTA   114268
PORTA   119021
PORTA   119406
```

I want to print this file in a pattern so that it will add values of column to based on owner name in column 1.

Output should look like:

```
LLCMO   216184
ONE 318584
PAZ 10478
NXT 11
PORTA   570539
```

Please suggest if a awk script can be written to find desired output.

Comment: `Please suggest if a awk script can be written to find desired output.` -- *Yes, it can be written.*

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk '{s[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in s) print i,s[i]}' file
```

Comment: tested the same but still name in column one appear more than 1 time and also adding 0 in end
$ awk '{s[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in s) print i,s[i]}' /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/Book2.csv

PORTA,119406 0

LLCMO,114198 0

PORTA,112005 0

ONE,107788 0

PAZ,10478 0

PORTA,119021 0

ONE,102419 0

PORTA,111170 0

LLCMO,101986 0

PORTA,114268 0

ONE,108377 0

PORTA,114075 0

NXT,11 0

Comment: @user2043380 Is the file comma seperated? It it is, then set the field separator to `,`, with `awk -F, ...`

Comment: hi i made some changes and now its working fine.

$ awk -F"," '{math[($2)]+=$4}END{for (i in math) {print i,math[i]}}' /cygdrive/
c/KPI/test/MRS_STEERED_FINAL.csv
TELEI 1116088
LLCMO 676921
SBP 1897868
ETC 32
COMUC 358381
CNG 338824410
NXT 325
KAT 433529
TLP 325739
MOV 226806
TCOMU 529325
DAEWO 3047593
PAZ 62691
ONE 705207
BITED 15273
PORTA 810970
TCJCK 365145

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple in pure bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A data

while read -r key value; do
    (( data[$key]+=value ))
done < file.txt

for curKey in "${!data[@]}"; do
    echo "$curKey ${data[$curKey]}"
done
```

Comment: +1 for the pure bash solution. I find awk more concise in this case, but I guess that is a matter of opinion

Comment: @user000001 both are great solutions. I'd prefer awk version as a standalone command and bash version as a part of a bigger bash script.